# Can I add users by simply adding new entries in /etc/passwd

Tags: users

I am adding a new node to my small "cluster". I would like the new node to have exactly the same accounts (for human users) on it. I tried to copy the human user entries from other node to this new node but I cannot login via ssh using these added account. Have I successfully added the new accounts by simply adding new entries in the /etc/passwd file? How can I examine it? (I googled about how to list all human users but all points to showing the content of /etc/passwd.)

Comment: Did you also copy the authorized keys (if you're using public key authentication) or `/etc/shadow` entries (if you're using passwords)?

Comment: I have the entire /home folder shared, so the keys are already there. I don't know about /etc/shadow which is probably the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most Linux systems, the absolute minimum to create for a local user is an entry in `/etc/passwd` and the corresponding entry in `/etc/shadow`.  Many times there's also a group with the same name in `/etc/group`.

Creating the user's home directory is also useful in most cases, depending on whether the home directory already exists on a file server and is automounted on the servers in your cluster.  The ssh authorized_keys file may be useful (as a comment already points out), and this is typically in a subdirectory under the home directory.

Using utility programs like `adduser` or `useradd` takes care of these steps for you.  One command covers everything except the ssh key.

Comment: Thanks. Copying /etc/shadow solved my problem. I have almost 20 users so copy these two files is much faster for me than using ```useradd``` to create accounts one by one.